# How do I remove all Celery results from a redis backend when a user's Flask session ends?

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

This is bit of a high level question as I may just have a poorly designed Flask app, but I currently have built an app where after user submits a form, a celery worker formats the input into a sql query and executes that query.

Now I have set up a Redis backend to keep the results, so when the task is done, I can display the results by getting It from Redis. However, I don't want these results to persist in Redis forever, but I do want them to persist for an entire user session in the app so they can view the results from previous queries while in the session.

How would I go about doing this? My instinct is to add the individual task ids to a session and when the user wuits the app, use forget() in celery to remove all the task ids.

Comment: you could take a look at `task_func.AsyncResult(task_id)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'result_expires' configuration flag and set it to ~5min. For more information: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires

Comment: @user3002486 did you try?